# FromBodyAttribute with string parameter requires double quotes of JSON ASP.NET CORE 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

The Post method below requires double quotes of JSON in the body like below

```
"{}"
```

Otherwise, exception

```
{"":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1."]}
```

The PostCar method below accepts JSON without double quotes like below, but requires custom model instead of string type.

```
{}
```

Is there a way to declare a post method like the Post method, but post html body without double quotes?

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        [HttpPost("PostCar")]
        public void PostCar([FromBody] Car car)
        {
        }    
    }

   public class Car
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }          
    }
```

This .NET Core feature is confusing!!

**Updates**

My current solution to avoid double quotes for JSON is below:

But JSON validation is required.

```
[HttpPost]
        public void Post()
        {     
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var body = reader.ReadToEnd();                       
            }

        }
```

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Sep/14/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-in-ASPNET-Core-API-Controllers#Reading-Request.Body-for-Raw-Data

Again, is there a better solution instead of using Request.Body, but like using [FromBody]?

[FromBody] with string parameter: This requires double quotes, less code, has NO JSON validation?

Comment: The quotes are required because and if your accepted content type is application/json. Just accept text/html and you're done.

Comment: please see my updates

Comment: I think you must configurate something on Startup.cs

Comment: How then? purpose of the thread

Comment: Use [FromBody]  only for serialized clases, .NET core only allows just one [FromBody] per api method

Comment: I don't understand how your request should look like. You write, that you want to send "html without quotes" and later you want json validation to be available. Next question is how do you define "Json validation" - valid json or valid data? If valid data, how do you plan to define validation rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use DefaultContractResolver class which is the part of Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization. The code will look like as below.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opt =>
      {
        if (opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver != null)
        {
          var resolver = opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver as DefaultContractResolver;
          resolver.NamingStrategy = null;
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Does it affect api or mvc?can you explain what it does by setting it to null? any links?

Comment: You can refer to this link. https://codeteddy.com/2017/06/06/create-api-with-asp-net-core-day-4-working-with-serializer-settings-and-content-negotiation-in-asp-net-core-api/  . Also there are some Pluralsight courses that explain serialisation

Answer (score 0):

Your post method accepts a string, so it cannot parse a JSON object. Wrapping your object in quotes essentially just serves to satisfy posting a JSON string as your body. In other words, the value of `value` will literally be `"{}"`. If you need to post a JSON object, then you need to bind to a param of some class type:

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]MyClass value)
{
}
```

Comment: Well, that is what I posted on my opening thread. I remember .NET does not require double quotes for JSON.

Comment: *Bind to a class*. That's the whole point. JSON is an *object* representation format, but you're not binding to an object. You're binding to a string, so since it's `[FromBody]`, the only acceptable post body is a JSON string.